# ASP.net WebForms PayPal IPN Falsely marked Success

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-ipn

I am working on fixing an issue with our sites Cart/Payment system.  Our site is written in C# ASP.NET WebForms

The problem is that the IPN response from PayPal doesn't appear to be running.  Checking the PayPal IPN History on the records in question, PayPal shows a 200 success response from my site.

I added a logging function on my site, so any hit to this page is getting logged, and I am not seeing hits to my notify page.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something incorrectly, or if they've changed something I need to review to get this more stable?

Here is how my site processes PayPal transactions:

With the invoice number, some text for the items, and the Total Charge, I populate a Named Value Collection and Post the information to PayPal:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("cmd", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("_xclick"));
nvc.Add("business", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("email@example.com"));
nvc.Add("currency_code", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("USD"));
nvc.Add("item_name", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(InvoiceText));
nvc.Add("no_shipping", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("1"));
nvc.Add("notify_url", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("https://example.com/ipn_PayPal.aspx"));
nvc.Add("invoice", InvoiceID);
nvc.Add("amount", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(TotalCharge.ToString()));
nvc.Add("image_url", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("https://example.com/Content/images/Logo.png"));
nvc.Add("return", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("https://example.com/?PayPalThanks=" + InvoiceID));
nvc.Add("rm", HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("2"));
HttpHelper.RedirectAndPOST(this.Page, PPFee.PostPage, nvc);
```

For reference her is the HttpHelper class:

```
public class HttpHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method prepares an Html form which holds all data in hidden field in the addetion to form submitting script.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The destination Url to which the post and redirection will occur, the Url can be in the same App or ouside the App.</param>
    /// <param name="data">A collection of data that will be posted to the destination Url.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a string representation of the Posting form.</returns>
    /// <Author>Samer Abu Rabie</Author>
    private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        //Set a name for the form
        string formID = "PostForm";

        //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
        strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + formID + "\" action=\"" + url + "\" method=\"POST\">");
        foreach (string key in data)
        {
            strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");
        }
        strForm.Append("</form>");

        //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + formID + ";");
        strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");

        //Return the form and the script concatenated. (The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
        return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
    }

    public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        //Prepare the Posting form
        string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);
        //Add a literal control the specified page holding the Post Form, this is to submit the Posting form with the request.
        page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
    }
}
```

Transactions do go to PayPal and people can pay normally, but after getting redirected back to my thank you page the IPN never seems to get sent.

On my IPN page, I start by checking for the Invoice, then I log it to a Database:

```
int Invoice = Utils.ReturnInt(Request.Form["invoice"], -1);
if (Invoice == -1)
    Invoice = Utils.ReturnInt(Request.QueryString["invoice"], 0);
LogInvHit(Invoice);
```

If the page was breaking on this, I would expect an error in PayPal's IPN history, so it's either getting past this, or never reaching it before assuming a 200 success

Also, for reference, this is how I tell PayPal if it was a Success:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strPayPalResponse);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
streamOut.Close();
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
```

In my estimation, if the page was getting hit, I should at least have an entry, but I don't, so I doubt my page is actually erroring out or getting an IPN hit from PayPal.

In Summary, I don't think the IPN notifications are working right, but am assuming I'm doing something incorrectly.  Looking for some help troubleshooting potential issues that I can correct

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how IPN delivery and verification works.

When PayPal posts a message to your listener, your listener will respond with some HTTP status code.  If it responds with a 2xx status, the IPN is marked as succssfully delivered.  If it does not respond with a 2xx status, the IPN will retry and eventually fail if no 2xx success is received in response.

---

The code you have highlighted, where your page was breaking, and where it posts the IPN back to PayPal for validation, has absolutely nothing to do with the above, (insofar as it does not impact the HTTP status code returned).

Posting the received IPN message back to PayPal for validation is for your own purposes, so you know the message came from PayPal and not some other entity.

Comment: But how is it getting a 200 from my listener when my listener shows nothing is hitting it?

Comment: It gets an HTTP 200 response because that's how your listener responded. Whether your listener fails in some way, including failing to record that something hit it, has no bearing if an HTTP response was sent, which is completely normal when a route on an HTTP server is accessed.

Comment: With the aspx page I'm using as a listener, the only way it would come back with a 200 is if it loaded, right?  Meaning my server side code should execute.  I don't understand how the page could return a 200 if it never loads.  I have custom errors off on this page, so if any of the code is failing I'd expect a 500 error being reported to PayPal.